# How can I keep the current navigator in Flutter while showing a login screen?

Tags: flutter, authentication

I am working on a flutter app which should require the user to enter a password or use biometrics to authenticate every time the app is resumed from the background.

I already have implemented the switching behaviour between the apps contents and the login screen with a FutureBuilder switching based on a boolean value of a Provider. This only replaces the first page of the Navigator such that the pages "on top" (e.g., a detail view opened from a list) are still shown regardless of login status. How would I implement this behaviour to always show the login screen when reopening the app?